# Nested routes undefined variable Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, nested, edit

I am trying to build nested routes and as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080) I m trying to edit my boat picture as `<%= link_to "edit", edit_boat_picture_path(@boat, picture) %>`. But when I try it, it throws an error `undefined local variable or method`picture' for #<#:0x007f9637811ee0>`

my picture controller is; (probably destroy is wrong also)

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_filter :load_parent

  def index
    @picture = @boat.pictures.all
  end

  def new
    @picture = @boat.pictures.new
  end

  def show
    @pictures = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create

    @picture = @boat.pictures.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      #flash[:success] = "Continue from here"
      render 'show'
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def edit
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])

    if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated picture."
      render 'show'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy

    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed picture."
    redirect_to @picture.boat
  end


  private

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :image)
    end

    def load_parent
     @boat = Boat.find(params[:boat_id])
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you should change

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_boat_picture_path(@boat, picture) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture) %>
```

The key there being changing `picture` to `@picture`. The reason to do this is that you're declaring `@picture` (an instance variable) in your controller, not `picture` (a local variable). When declaring and defining an instance variable in a method in your controller, it's also accessible in the corresponding view. However, when declaring a local variable in a method in your controller, it is not available in your view.

So even if you *had* declared `picture` rather than `@picture` in your controller method, it wouldn't be accessible in your view, since it's a local variable.

For more information on the five types of ruby variables, see [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm).

Comment: Yes it works that way, I tried. But did not understand the logic behind it.

Comment: I edited my answer to add some explanation, does it help at all?

Comment: You defined `@picture` in the controller's action, but you were trying to acces to the `picture` variable, which does not exist. `@variables` are shared between the controller's action(s) and the view(s), whereas `variables` are just local variables, only existing in the local context (controller's action OR a single view OR a single block, etc.)